# Generic function creates generic object of arguments base

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }

    private static void DoSomething<T>(T obj)
    {
        var generic = new Generic<T>();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    // properties/methods
}

public class Generic<T>
{
    // properties/methods
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.DoSomething(); // instantiates Generic<Foo> instead of Generic<Bar>
    }
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate a generic class from a derived method with the current type instead of the base type?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - The compiler can infer the generic argument is `Foo` from the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compile-time type of `this` within `Foo.DoSomething` is just `Foo`, so the compiler can *only* infer the type argument as `Foo`.

The simplest way of getting it to do it based on the execution-time type is probably:

```
DoSomething((dynamic) this);
```

Alternatively, you could call it with reflection yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest sollution!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is it's resolving `T` to the *compile time* type of where you're calling the method. In this case, it's being called/resolved from within `Foo.Something` and the compile-time type of `this` is `Foo`, not `Bar`.

One option is to make the call `virtual` and have each type `override` it. This will make each time provide compile-time type information when calling the method:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }

    //notice this is protected now so it's accessible to `Bar`
    protected static void DoSomething<T>(T obj)
    {
        var generic = new Generic<T>();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the Dynamic Language Runtime to have it resolve the type at runtime:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        dynamic thisDynamic = this;
        DoSomething(thisDynamic);
    }

    private static void DoSomething<T>(T obj)
    {
        var generic = new Generic<T>();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you're not using .NET 4.0 and don't have access to the Dynamic Language Runtime, you can employ generics as well:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this);
    }

    private static void DoSomething(object obj)
    {
        Type runtimeType = obj.GetType();
        MethodInfo createMethod = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("CreateGeneric", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var genericCreateMethod = createMethod.MakeGenericMethod(runtimeType);
        genericCreateMethod.Invoke(null, new[]{obj});
    }

    private static void CreateGeneric<T>(T obj)
    {
        var generic = new Generic<T>();
    }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming you need the `T obj` parameter in the `CreateGeneric` method. If you don't actually need it, you can update the method signature and calling reflection code to omit it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I used the sollution Jon presented, it was the easiest to implement.